# Having eval() recognize the VueJS eventBus

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get eval() to recognize the VueJS eventBus when being called.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to evaluate:

```
eval("eventBus.$emit('eventName');");
```

But I'm getting the error "eventBus is not defined, despite the eventBus being imported and working outside of the eval function.

Is there anyway to set the scope of eval to that of the Vue instance so eventBus is recognized?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

---

More Information

In my project I'm using Blockly, which runs individual block code by processing a string of code set to a block, and calling eval() on it.

this is my runCode method, inside of a VueJS component

```
.....
runCode: function() {
    // Generate JavaScript code and run it.
    window.LoopTrap = 1000;
    Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP =
        'if (--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop.";\n';
    var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(this.workspace);
    Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
    try {
      eval(code); //Eval call here
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  },
....
```

This is a generalized version of setting the code mapped to the block I want to execute.

```
Blockly.JavaScript['blockName'] = function(block) {
      let code = "eventBus.$emit('eventName');";
      return code;
};
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`.

Comment: If you replace the code `eval("eventBus.$emit('eventName');");` with simply `eventBus.$emit('eventName');`, then your code starts working? There are no other modifications necessary to make it work? This seems extremely surprising to me; the only explanation I can think of is that your code is being transpiled somehow so that the code you're writing is not the code that's running. Could that be the case? Or, can you provide a complete example?

Comment: @SLaks https://youtu.be/MFtijdklZDo?t=912

Comment: this is a perfectly safe way to use eval. there's no possible way to exploit this example whatsoever. that said, if this is indeed a realistic example it's also 100% pointless as you could just as easily just run the code directly.

Comment: I've updated my question to show why I'm using eval.